# Check if command is executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, var, discord.js

I have a problem with my restriction system for commands.
The message 'you don't have permission' will only run once (when you don't have the role). I'm aware that if you don't set a var (in this case `checkrole`) the code will be executed once however, I don't know how to check when a command is executed.

So I could do something like this:

```
if  (command === ' ') {
    checkrole = false
}
```

Code of interest:

```
if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["someone"].includes(r.name.toLowerCase())) && checkrole === false) {
    checkrole = true;
    return message.channel.send('Sorry, but you do not have the **permissions** to do that.');
  }
```

(var checkrole is defined - it begins as false (`var checkrole = false;`))

Kind regards,
Ruben

Comment: I guess you need to have the checkrole variable for all of your users! unless you only have one. and if you are using this code in the server and want to send a message to the user only once if they are restricted, you can keep the checkrole variable in database for each user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you want to use commands you need a prefix. Once you chose that, you know that the content of the message ([`Message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)) will start with `prefix + command`. So you could write it like this:

```js
// Assuming that:
// var prefix = '-'; for example
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "mycommand")) {
  checkrole = false;
}
```

Although this works, there are more efficient ways to use commands, especially if you'll need to use arguments and so on...
Reading [this guide](https://anidiotsguide_old.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/content/getting-started/your-basic-bot.html) might help you: it covers the basics but also more advanced stuff ;)